# Ratio test of convergence for series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a series $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} x_j$ and a condition saying that $\liminf_{n \to \infty}\frac{\left|x_{n+1}\right|}{\left|x_n\right|}>1$ one can easily show that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \left| x_j \right| $ diverges to $+\infty$ because $\exists N$ such that $\left| x_{N+m} \right| > \left| x_N \right| L^m$ where $L >1$. But what can one say about $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} x_j$ itself? Does it necessarily diverge or it can be conditionally convergent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: look a the sequence $(x_j)$; in order that $\sum x_j$ be (conditionally) convergent, $(x_j)$ has to be a $0$-sequence.

Comment: Thanks, I think that exactly what I was missing. Indeed, for $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} x_j$ to converge it must be $x_j\to 0$ or equivalently $\left| x_j \right| \to 0$. Thus we can conclude that $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} x_j$ diverges (but not necessarily to $\infty$ as it is the case for $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \left| x_j \right|$ ), right?

Comment: @SergeyZykov Yes, the series must diverge, but not necessarily to $ \infty$ or $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

The partial sums cannot converge (even conditionally) because eventually the magnitude of each term is greater than any given number.

Comment: but those terms can be of different signs and can cancel one another, can not they?

Comment: No: $1-2+4-8+\cdots$ will not converge, no matter how you change the signs, and this is essentially the situation you are in.